# loadJSON with lat and lon and get the variables

Tags: javascript, json, p5.js

I am loading  JSON file and I want to take the latitude and longitude variables from file. 
Am doing it with **let lat = row.get('lat');** but it doesn't work and in the const pix = yMap.latLngToPixel(data.lat,data.lon); it says that it doesn't recognize it .
How can I do it to work right, 'cause after that I want to take the json file from localhost, this is why I am using a p5.js library.

```
<title>Mappa </title>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.16/p5.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mappa-mundi@0.0.4" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="mappa.js" ></script>
```

**Json.file (like the one that I will take from localhost)**

```
{"conflicts":[
{ "Place":"Afganistan",
"lat":33.0000,
"lon":65.0000 }
,
{"Place": "Koln",
"lat":17.0500,
"lon":-61.8000}
,
 {"Place": "ai",
 "lat":18.2500,
 "lon": -63.166}

  ]
 }
  }
```

**js.file**

```
let data;

let myMap;
let canvas;

const mappa = new Mappa ('Leaflet');

const options = {
lat: 39.074207, 
lng: 21.824312,
zoom: 2,
style: "http://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
}

function preload(){
data = loadJSON ("conflicts.json");

//var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);

}



function setup(){

canvas = createCanvas(1350,600); 
myMap = mappa.tileMap(options); 
myMap.overlay(canvas);


 let lat = row.get('lat');
 let lon = row.get('lon');

}

 function draw() {
clear();
const pix = myMap.latLngToPixel(data.lat,data.lon);
fill (255,0,200);
ellipse (pix.x,pix.y,20,20); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `data` is a an object with a single property which is an array. To access each element in this array, you need to iterate it:

```
 for (let item of data.conflicts)
    draw(item)


 function draw(item) {
    const pix = myMap.latLngToPixel(item.lat, item.lon);
    fill (255,0,200);
    ellipse (pix.x,pix.y,20,20); 
 }
```

Comment: I tried this with for loop and your solution either, but the lat and lon in const pix = myMap.latLngToPixel(item.lat, item.lon); there is also an error in lat and lon.

Comment: i did this but its fail again:   function setup(){

canvas = createCanvas(1350,600); 
myMap = mappa.tileMap(options); 
myMap.overlay(canvas);

for (let item of data.conflicts){
  let lan = conflicts.lat;
  let lon = conflicts.lon;
    draw(item)
}
}

 function draw(item) {
  clear();
    const pix = myMap.latLngToPixel(item.lat, item.lon);
    fill (255,0,200);
    ellipse (pix.x,pix.y,20,20); 
 }

Comment: If you add `console.log(item)` in `draw`, what does it log?

Comment: p5.maps Loaded ✓
mappa.js:42 {Place: "Afganistan", lat: 33, lon: 65}
mappa.js:42 {Place: "Koln", lat: 17.05, lon: -61.8}
mappa.js:42 {Place: "ai", lat: 18.25, lon: -63.166}
mappa.js:42 undefined

Comment: but the error is here: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'lat' of undefined
    at draw (mappa.js:44)

Comment: Your output makes me think there's one more member in your array which is undefined.